# Tkinter window does not open when running after compiling python script to .exe with PyInstaller

Tags: tkinter, pyinstaller, exe, python-3.9

After I compile a Python script (which I named`bobux.py`) to a .exe with PyInstaller, the .exe does absolutely nothing when run except open a CMD window for 4 seconds. Even when I run it from the command line and recompile it with `pyinstaller bobux.py -Fwd all --onefile --icon=icon.ico`, I don't see any errors. I do see a lot of warnings in the `build/bobux/warn-bobux.txt` file, some even showing that Python didn't recognize a module to be written in Java, making it not recognize `java.<whatever java thing>` as a Python module. I also opened the .exe in a hex editor and clearly saw that it had the Tkinter files.

So what is wrong here?

Here's the original code I compiled:

```
from tkinter import Tk, messagebox, Button
from webbrowser import open

# It's literally just a joke program, but idk why it breaks as soon as I compile it. :/

def a():
    open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ')

root = Tk()

root.geometry('300x300')
root.title("☺")

b = Button(root, text='Free robux no scam hahahahahaaha', command=a)
b.pack()
```

And my spec file too:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['bobux.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\20059053\\Documents'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='bobux',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Also:

- The resulting .exe is absolutely MASSIVE (20.8 MB!) How can I fix this?
- I tried this with a different script that only uses Tkinter and it works just fine (despite also keeping a terminal window up for 4 seconds as well). Is it because of importing `webbrowser` that it's not working?

Comment: Your program does not contains `root.mainloop()`

Comment: Without this, your program won't load the window

Comment: Oh... I guess I'll try that

Comment: It works! Also how can I make the .exe's massive size smaller?

Comment: I won't be able to help you with that as I generally use `auto-py-to-exe` in order to convert .py to .exe